Does an unopened inner tube with sealant inside have an expiry date?
I know if the tube with sealant is mounted on a bicycle it usually is efficient for 6-12 months or for a few punctures.
However, if the inner tube with prefilled sealant is unopened (on the shelf), is there an expiration date?
I am especially interested in the sealant quality degradation due to storage and not tube quality degradation..
Some people mention that the sealant degrades when it comes innto contact with air. An unopened, sealant prefilled tube has some air in it, is that sufficient contact to cause degradation?
Example of tube with prefilled sealant:


Tire sealant is generally made from latex, which when exposed to air has a life time of 6 months to a year. But when sealed, the shelf life is measured in years.
This means the tube would have to go bad before the sealant starts going bad. I don't think there would be a simple answer to this question as tubes generally last a very long time when stored properly.

I assume that in sealant prefilled inner tube, there is some amount of air. Does it make any difference ?

The same could be said for the sealant in the tires, and yet, there's a need to top up periodically. For this reasoning to be true, it should imply that tires/tubes are as impermeable to air (or ammonia) than the sealant package. I mention ammonia because I understand it prevents the coagulation of the latex molecules, so if ammonia evaporates, there will be a coagulation.
